# Post additional model values to database in views.py not modelform

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

model

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(blank=False,max_length=256,default='')
    last_name = models.CharField(blank=False,max_length=256,default='')
    plan = models.CharField(blank=False,max_length=256,default='')   
    plan_price = models.CharField(blank=False,max_length=256,default='')
```

Views.py

```
if request.method == 'POST':

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save(commit=True)
        return index(request)
```

In my modelForm I accept 3 values from the user: first_name, last_name, and plan. I dont have any problem with posting to the database from the form, what i am trying to find out is how I can say something like this

```
if plan = 'plan1':
    #set plan_price to '$399'
else
    #set plan_price to '$699'

#then post first_name, last_name, plan, plan_price to database
```

Comment: Do you have a fix mapping from plans to prices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
if form.is_valid():
    person = form.save(commit=False)
    plans = {
        'plan1': 399,
        'plan2': 699,
        # ...
    }
    person.plan_price = plans.get(person.plan, some_default)
    person.save()
    return index(request)  
    # you might consider a redirect instead so as not to have the same content on various urls
```

If the plan price always should match the plan you can also override the model's `save` method and leave the view as you had it:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    # ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.plan_price = some_logic(self.plan)
        super(Person, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But then, you could replace that field by a property alltogether as it seems redundant. If plans, for instance, change prices, I would consider a `Plan` model with a name and price field.

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you. I actually put both answer together to get the final working code. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

in your createview you can use this function and write your code there

```
    def form_valid(self, form):
        if self.object.plan = 'plan1':
            form.instance.price = 399
        else:
            [...]
        return super(your_class_name, self).form_valid(form)
```

you can access the created object fields by `self.object.filed`